# Activity/Fragments & Action Bar

Tags: android, listview, tabs, android-actionbar, fragment

I'm really new to Android and I want to implement listview and tab action bar:

Home page:

- A list that has action bar on top with two tabs (swipe left/right).
- The items in the list are clickable.

Detail page:

- One of the tab will just have some content
- The other is another list with unclickable items

What should I use?
A listview activity or a listview fragment for the home page?

Or does anyone know of an example that is similar to this?
I don't care about backwards compatibility (for now)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this Android Developers' tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) is pretty self explanatory. You should be able to figure it out from that.

I'd suggest you go with fragments as they're the newest way; whereas activities are getting old now. This will make it easier for your application to accommodate future Android updates.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958458/actionbar-3-tabs-and-3-fragments-this-is-killing-me) may also help you out regarding Fragments.

Comment: No problem. Hope it helped!

Comment: When you say `whereas activities are getting old now`, I believe that you are correct, but are you saying that in the context of `Creating multiple screens as activities` is getting "old" and that the recommended way of doing so is with fragments?

Comment: @JimG. I'm just saying that `Fragments` are recommended by Android to use now instead of an `Activity`. `Activities` still have their place but in the main you want to use `Fragments`, where you can, from now really.