# ActionBarCompat + tabs: remove Fragment Menu Item when switching?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-actionbar-compat

For each Fragment I will add Menu Items to provide the user with context related actions. But when switching to another Fragment, the Menu items stayed. So I can end with all options from each fragment in the menu.

*How do you **clean** the menu item to have only the ones set up in the activity menu?*

I read about invalidateOptionMenu() and onPrepareOPtionmenu() but I don't really get how they work. **What is the correct way to implement it ?**

Anyway, how is it that removing fragment-linked menu item when the fragment is not displayed anymore is not native Android behavior?

EDIT if instrucitons not clear enough.

- I have **one** activity supporting Navigation_Mode_Tabs with **settings** as global menu item.
- I start fragA that add itemA1 and itemA2. So I have **setting, itemA1, itemA2**. So far, so good.
- Then I switch to fragB that add its own itemB. HERE, I have **settings, itemA1, itemA2, itemB** in the menu !

*Why itemA1 and itemA2 are stuck? How to remove them?*

EDIT 2 : I have try another set up of tabulation from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958458/actionbar-3-tabs-and-3-fragments-this-is-killing-me?rq=1) and it suddenly menu items seems to be correctly remove ! 
It's something to see with the use of **remove(R.id.container, fragment)** versus the **onDetach()/onAttach()** that Google recommands [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

I am looking at this, probably tomorrow I'll update. Please, if you know about this, share :)

Answer (score 0):

you could set the menuinflater on each activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.demo, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ? I have one activity and several fragments for each one I use onCreateOptionsMenu to set the menu item. 
I don't get how this could solve my problem, but thanks

Comment: if you call an other fragment, you could override the current Optionsmenu

Comment: yes, it's what I do. I know no other way to add fragment related item menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should add TabListener to your tabs and call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` in `onTabSelected()` method. It cause call `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. You should override it in your activity and inflate menu for selected fragment. If you add menu items from code don't forget to clear menu for previous fragment.

Comment: I have already tried with invalidateOptionMenu() in onTabSelect(). I don't use support one for I have appcompat ActionBarActivity. 
See my last edit if you still are interested in this issue.