# ActionBar Crash Android

Tags: java, android, crash, android-actionbar

I'm having a problem with the action bar, I explain well.
So if I'm on a tab (selected say) if there cliccassi accidentally crashes the app I wish there does not happen ... But I can not understand.
I'll post a bit 'of the code that I put in the MAIN ACTIVITY FOR THE CONFIGURATION OF TAB.

```
private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment mFragment;

    private final Activity mActivity;

    private final String mTag;

    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {

        mActivity = activity;

        mTag = tag;

        mClass = clz;

    }
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        // Check if the fragment is already initialized

        if (mFragment == null) {

            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity

            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());

            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);


        } else {

            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.show(mFragment);
            //ft.attach(mFragment);

        }

    }
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if (mFragment != null) {

            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached

           // ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.hide(mFragment);
        }

    }
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            ft.replace(tab.getPosition(),mFragment);

        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }

}
```

log:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must use non-zero containerViewId
at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:384)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:379)
at com.megadonate.megadownloader.MainActivity$TabListener.onTabReselected(MainActivity.java:158)
at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:577)
at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1084)
at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:537)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17318)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: Added in the main post

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that you perform a transaction [commit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29) in your `FragmentTransaction`. 
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958458/actionbar-3-tabs-and-3-fragments-this-is-killing-me) post for a guide.